# Byte wise modification in a specific range of a jpg image (treated as a binary object)

Tags: python, image, compiler-errors, binary, byte

I am testing to write data at the end of a .jpg file. As i know all the .jpg files begin by FFD8 and end by FFD9. Using that fact i succeeded in writting "Hello World!" at the end of my .jpg file with a function that looks like this:

```
def writte_at_the_end_of_jpg_fct (img_path:str, msg:str):
      with open(img_path, 'ab') as fimg:
      fimg.write(b"Hello World!")
```

And Indeed i get:
[image]

But now how can i do to remove only the data that i ve added at the end of the file (that means "Hllo World!"

I ve tried this:

```
def erase_data_in_img_fct(img_jpg_file_path: str) -> None:
    with open(img_jpg_file_path, 'rb') as fimg:
        content = fimg.read()
        offset = content.index(bytes.fromhex('FFD9'))
        end_i = fimg.seek(offset + 2)

    with open(img_jpg_file_path, 'ab') as fimg:
        fimg = fimg[0:end_i]
```

But it didn't work, i get this error:

> TypeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object is not subscriptable

I have searched a lot of time on the web an answer to my problem and didn't found it.

Thank you

Comment: try replacing `fimg = fimg[0:end_i]` with `fimg.write(fimg.read(end_i))`

Comment: and use `wb` if you want to clean write your file instead of `ab`

Comment: @sudden_appearance thank you for your answer. I only want yo erase a part of the image

Comment: @sudden_appearance Your solution doesn't work, neither with 'ab' or 'wb'. With 'ab' i get this error: "io.UnsupportedOperation: read". With 'wb' it's even worse all the data of the image are erased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [bytes.rindex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.rindex) instead because the `ffd9` bytes may occur multiple times in the file:

```
$ diff -u old.py new.py 
--- old.py  2022-06-08 08:07:33.381031019 +0100
+++ new.py  2022-06-08 08:07:45.581315987 +0100
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 def erase_data_in_img_fct(img_jpg_file_path: str) -> None:
     with open(img_jpg_file_path, 'rb') as fimg:
         content = fimg.read()
-        offset = content.index(bytes.fromhex('FFD9'))
+        offset = content.rindex(bytes.fromhex('FFD9'))
         end_i = fimg.seek(offset + 2)
 
-    with open(img_jpg_file_path, 'ab') as fimg:
-        fimg = fimg[0:end_i]
+    with open(img_jpg_file_path, 'wb') as fimg:
+        fimg.write(content[:end_i])
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. i ll try your code as soos as i can (the code in your answer is a correction to my function yes?)

Comment: I've updated the answer to only include the changes.